# Application logs on AWS Linux2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We are using Linux2 platform with ElasticBeanstalk. Prior to this, we were on Linux 1 and logs were being retrieved and visible in the Elasticbeanstalk console. However, post migration to Linux2, none of the application logs are visible. I've tried configurations mentioned in the docs by adding the following content to .ebextensions/logs.config
files for the following sections:
"/opt/elasticbeanstalk/tasks/bundle/applogs.conf" :
"/opt/elasticbeanstalk/tasks/publishlogs.d/applogs.conf" :

and various combinations of these, but none seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

On **Amazon Linux 2** (AL2) you setup logging differently than on AL1. What you tried is for AL1, thus it does not work on AL2.

For AL2 your log configurations should go into folder
`/opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/logtasks/bundle`.

For example you can create a log config file using `.ebextentions` and [file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-files):

```
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/logtasks/bundle/my-go-app.conf
```

with the content of

```
/var/app/current/log/*.log
```

where `/var/app/current/log/*.log` would be location of your custom application logs. It can be other location of file off course. This is just an **example** of a log config file.